# having trouble calculating distance in centimeters through windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation

I developed an app to read distance between two locations on windows phone 7 . But while testing the app, whenever i move some centimeters, it starts to give value in 13000's.

```
    Public Sub watcher1_PositionChanged(sender As Object, e As GeoPositionChangedEventArgs(Of GeoCoordinate))
    Dim dCoord As GeoCoordinate
    Dim currentDistance As Double
    Dim convertedDistance As Double
    dCoord = New GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude)

    If mlastCoordinate.Latitude <> 0.0 Then

        'distanceText.Text = e.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString()
        currentDistance = mlastCoordinate.GetDistanceTo(dCoord)
        mDistance = startCoordinate.GetDistanceTo(dCoord)
        ' mDistance += currentDistance
        'mDistance = Math.Round(mDistance, 2)
        'Dim distance As String
        'distance = String.Format("%.2", mDistance)
        If selectedSystemState.Equals("centi") Then
            convertedDistance = mDistance * 100
        ElseIf selectedSystemState.Equals("meter") Then
            convertedDistance = mDistance
        ElseIf selectedSystemState.Equals("inches") Then
            convertedDistance = mDistance * 39.37
        ElseIf selectedSystemState.Equals("feet") Then
            convertedDistance = mDistance * 3.28
        End If

        convertedDistance = Math.Round(convertedDistance, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The distance you are getting [is in meters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto.aspx). So, 13000 centimeters is 130 meters - unless we know what and how you move, this seems like a very plausible value.

Answer (score 0):

How are you instantiating the Location Service - If you're not using `GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High)` you'll likely be using Cell Tower data, which can be off by many 100s of metres.

Even if you are using GPS the accuracy of civilian GPS units is only in the order of 5-10m, so measuring distances in cm or inches is really beyond these things.

You should probably check the `GeoCoordinate.HorizontalAccuracy` to see what the "noise" is likely to be.